# PostgreSQL - REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW while pg_dump

Tags: postgresql-9.3, materialized-view, pg-dump

(Version 9.3)

Asking this after searching around without any solution:

- I create a simple materialized view (in practice, I have a few of them).
- I call `pg_dump` to backup the database.
- While `pg_dump` is running, I try to refresh the view using `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`.
- The `REFRESH` statement hangs (remains 'active') as long as `pg_dump` is active (this makes things even worse as while the view hangs on `REFRESH`, I cannot `SELECT` from it as well).

My question is: how can I `REFRESH` materialized views while performing a dump?

I don't mind excluding the data of the view from the dump if this will help, I don't need to save the data. But I also wouldn't want to complicate my dump command to an unreasonable amount just to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

Complete list of commands:

```
psql my_db -c "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS (SELECT * FROM my_table);"
pg_dump -Fc my_db
(in a different process, while pg_dump is active:)
psql my_db -c "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view;"
```